# Positioning hover/pop-up div with CSS - a glyph browser web page

Tags: css

I'm trying to make a glyph browser web page

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Glyph browser</title>
    <style>     
                body {
            background-color: black;
        }
        .gridcontainer {
            margin-left: 3rem;
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: repeat(16, 1fr);
            }
        .gridcell {
            color: white;
            border: 0.1px solid gray;
            padding: 1rem;
            text-align: center;
            }
        
        p {
            text-align: center;
            margin: 2rem;
            font-size: 1rem;
            color: white;
        }
        
        p.unicode {
            font-size: 0.5rem;
            }
        .glyph-pop {
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 10;
        }
        .glyph-display {
            font-size: 5rem;
        }
        .glyph:hover .glyph-pop
        {
            display: inline-block;
        }
        .glyph-pop p {
            background-color: black;
            font-size: 20rem;
            color: orange;
        }
        .glyph-pop .unicode {
            color: orange;
            font-size: 2rem;
            }
        
        .glyph a {
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: inherit;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>
    Glyph browser
</h1>
<div class="gridcontainer">
    <div class="glyph">
        <p class="glyph-display" title="exclamation mark Punctuation, Other">
            <a>!</a>
        </p>
        <p class="unicode">
            0021
        </p>
        <div class="glyph-pop">
            <p>
                !
            </p>
            <p class="unicode">
                U+0021
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="glyph">
        <p class="glyph-display" title="exclamation mark Punctuation, Other">
            <a>@</a>
        </p>
        <p class="unicode">
            0022
        </p>
        <div class="glyph-pop">
            <p>
                @
            </p>
            <p class="unicode">
                U+0022
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="glyph">
        <p class="glyph-display" title="exclamation mark Punctuation, Other">
            <a>#</a>
        </p>
        <p class="unicode">
            0023
        </p>
        <div class="glyph-pop">
            <p>
                #
            </p>
            <p class="unicode">
                U+0023
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The idea is to display a glyph large when the user hovers over a small version. (Sizes will probably get adjusted.)

[image: moving over the glyphs displays larger image]

It's working OK-ish, but I can't control the location of the 'large' glyph display, and I'm not sure what's possible. Ideally I could place the larger one just below the smaller one.

Comment: if my answer is correct can you make accept? Thanks

Comment: if my question is well asked, can you upvote it? 